# UIImageView | unrecognized selector sent to instance | Xcode 6.4 | iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, unrecognized-selector

I'm new at Xcode, and my task was to migrate the code from **iOS 6.1 to 8.4**, but there where so many deprecated methods. I solved them (I hope so), but now I got a new problem.

The code I'm using is this one:

```
[self.clientImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_client.imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

And I get this error:

**[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe937a88b0**

And finally, I get this:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbe937a88b0'**

Thank you so much.

Comment: It's true, there is no such method. Perhaps it was a category method added through some library you were using.

Comment: You are using SDWebImage to load your image from url.

Comment: @Rajatp | Yes, I'm using it, versión 3.7.0, but I don't know what may be not working right :c

Comment: Did you import `SDWebImage`?

Comment: NSLog both your `_client.imageURL` and `self.clientImageView` and try to find out whether any of them nil or not.

Comment: @Larme - Yes, I imported it, well... the one working in this project before me did it, He has de framework added.

Comment: @Rajatp There's no need to log anything. That won't help at all.

Comment: Make sure you are targeting the `SDWebImage.m` file so it gets linked into your project.

Comment: @Rajatp - I'll check if is the view, 'cause I checked already the _client.imageURL and it never nil.

Comment: @rmaddy i am using this library and it is working perfectly for me.So just curios to know whether any nil object is crashing the app or not.

Comment: @rmaddy - Thanks, I think it was not targeted correctly to the SDWebImage.m file, let me check if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Collaborator of[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

> See https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#add-linker-flag. Correctly
>   setting the flags should take care of the issue. BTW: I strongly
>   recommend you guys switch to CocoaPods, that way those issues will
>   never arise.

Comment: I'll try to switch to CocoaPods, because all the flags and all of that is correct.

Comment: Try that, may be that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you imported the framework and set up all of the right flags, try to delete the contents of this folder `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and fun a clean build. It should help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add -ObjC in other linker flags and added sdwebcache.a in link libraries
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste all files from the library in your project. I tried everything suggested and nothing worked. At the end, simple copy paste do the work.

Also, I must say that I didn't have this problem on the new project, just in existing one. On the new project everything worked just fine.