# crash use sd_setImageWithURL in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

Hi I'm using `SDWebImage` for loading images in my `TableView` and through pods I have installed library in my project and when I run below code I'm getting exception like below can some one help me please..

### code:-

```
#import <UIImageView+WebCache.h>
 [cell.mainimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]
                  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

### Exception:-

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f93c3409c80'
```

Comment: try by adding libSDWebimage.a framework in linked framework and libraries section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImageView | unrecognized selector sent to instance | Xcode 6.4 | iOS 8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255040/uiimageview-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-xcode-6-4-ios-8-4)

Comment: Did you installed SDWebImage with CocoaPods?

Comment: yes installed through cocoa pods

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

instead of

```
#import<UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this?

`Add linker flags`

Update your target's (or project's) build settings to include the following `"Other Linker Flags"`:

`-ObjC`

`-all_load`

Comment: Why don't you just include the SDWebImage source files in your main project? This is how I incorporated SDWebImage, and the SDWebImage docs themselves state: "There are two ways to use this in your project: copy all the files into your project, or import the project as a static library." If you do this there is no need to open the SDWebImage project, compile the framework, link the framework with your project, etc.

Comment: @Krish have you added libSDWebImage.a to Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries?

Comment: i am getting error if i add libSDWebImage.a in Build Pahses

Comment: ld: library not found for -lSDWebImage
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: @Krish have you renamed your project?

Comment: make sure you have opened `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj` file

Comment: did you ever figure this out...i have the same sequence of problems with adding the library and getting `clang: error`