# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' in SDWEbImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am trying to load images in my Table-list cells and for this i am using `SDWebImage` with pod `'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'`.

Since 4 days on words I am getting exception like below

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79685270**

Please can someone help me find what I'm doing wrong in my code

### code:-

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
#import "UIImageView+Cached.h"

[cell.mainimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: is there UIImageView's object?

Comment: yes there is UIImageView's in object

Comment: try to update SDWebImage. Becuase I have same code and its working at my end.

Comment: what is updated code?

Comment: SDWebImage', '~>3.8' is not updated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImageView | unrecognized selector sent to instance | Xcode 6.4 | iOS 8.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255040/uiimageview-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-xcode-6-4-ios-8-4)

Comment: Just try to update code, Make sure you haven't specified any version on pod file. If update available then it's directly into your code.

Comment: i am using updated code in swift it's working fine but not objective-c

Comment: hello @himanth those answers not working for me why did you mark it's a duplicate?

Comment: those are not working

Comment: @Krish do you get any autocomplete from xcode? Can you past some of the rest of the code? like the class and the method you are calling this from?

Answer (score 0):

Podfile

platform :ios, '7.0'.
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

If you are using Swift, be sure to add use_frameworks! and set your target to iOS 8+:

platform :ios, '8.0' .
use_frameworks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the extension cannot be found at runtime.

You need to make sure that your project is linked with the framework in the right way.

You can try the following:

1. run `pod update SDWebImage` in the terminal - if you are getting the error since you updated the version
2. change the way you use the framework, using `@import SDWebImage;`

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope you find this useful**

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
              placeholderImage:nil
                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                            if (error) {
                              self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPlaceholderImageName"];
                            } else {
                              self.imageView.image = image;
                            }
}];
```